# Qlik Sense Cloud SQL Equivalent in Expression

Tags: where-clause, qlikview, qliksense

I have 2 fields - `pace` and `date`. I'm trying to return the `pace` value for the highest `date`. I can get the date by `max(Table.Date)`, but not sure how to refer to the `pace` value associated with it.

In SQL I know it would be something like:

```
select 
  pace 
where 
  date = max(date)
```

Comment: Did you consult the [copious amount of documentation available to you online](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2017/Content/Home.htm)?

Comment: how/where are you trying to get the result? Script? Chart/table/textbox etc?

Comment: I'm trying to put the result in a KPI chart.  I'm using this expression as the subtitle.  That date has a pace value that I want to display as the KPI.

Comment: And yes, I searched Qlik Help, Qlik Community, the user guide, the documentation from the Qlik class, StackOverflow, and general Google comments.  It has to be something simple that I'm just not getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression that uses [set analysis](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2017/Subsystems/Hub/Content/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm) to achieve this:

`= sum ( {< date = {"$(=Max(date))"} >} pace )`

Bear in mind that `max(date)` will be different based on your selections. If you don't have anything selected `max(date)` will be the max possible date in the data set. If you have selected `year = 2017` (for example) then `max(date)` will be the max possible date for 2017 (eventually 2017-12-31)

If you always want to show the max possible date no matter what the selections are then the calculation will be:

`= sum ( {1< date = {"$(=Max( {1} date))"} >} pace )`

But you can read more about `set analysis` on the help page or around the internet

You can view quick example [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q0XGR7DBQ2lrqEF0ds1qignqgGdFXlHm)